# Is it possible to do an image search on tumblr via api or rss method?

Tags: image, api, search, rss, tumblr

I would like to search tumblr.com from my app, using some api (did not see any search methods in their api) or via rss of their tags.  Is this possible?

Hopefully not by using google ajax search....

Also, I see websites like tumblow doing this via twitter api calls but that is also not ideal.  I would like to retrieve similar results to what you get when you just search in tumblr.